# Eclipse metrics plugin suggestion

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, metrics, code-metrics

I'm looking for a tool to give me some code metrics (total LOCs, LOC/Class, # of external references/class, etc...).

Does anyone know a good eclipse plugin that could provide me some some code metrics?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[here](http://metrics.sourceforge.net/) is one called Metrics.

**edit:**

i put together a short program for this screenshot in eclipse 3.3.1.1:

**Edit 2**
[Metrics New version](http://metrics2.sourceforge.net/) Thanks @mpartel for the link

Comment: This looks kind of old. Their latest news: "New release for Eclipse 3.1    2005-07-08".

Comment: just installed it at home on the mac.  looks good on 3.3.1.1

Comment: I've been researching metrics plug-ins recently.  Since this is the accepted answer, I wanted to point out to future readers looking for metrics plugins (like me) that a couple of the other answers mention 'metrics2'.  The metrics2 project claims that metrics.sourceforge.net is discontinued, so metrics2 is intended to be a continuation of it. As of the writing of this comment, the last release was Jul 2010 and code was last committed as recently as 6 days ago.

Comment: Metrics 2 home page: http://metrics2.sourceforge.net/

Comment: FYI: I can't get Metrics 2 to show up in a fresh install of Eclipse. It may or may not work anymore either.

Comment: Works for me on fresh Install - Dec 2012. Check that you've done the show views thing :-) Dear Eclipse when I install a plugin the odds are on I want the views shown and the thing enabled without my having to step through every menu ever.

Comment: The screenshot is no longer hosted at Imageshack, please update!

Comment: metric 2 didn't work with eclipse mars

Comment: Metrics 2 works for me in Eclipse 26.  Requires a manual install from their update site.  See link above from @mpartel.

Answer (score 28):

CodePro AnalytiX originally form Instantiations is now free at Google:

http://code.google.com/javadevtools/download-codepro.html

Comment: Why are there no updated metrics plugins for Luna!

Answer (score 17):

Sorry for the necropost but it seems like the right thing to do since this was my starting point. Try [Metrics2](http://metrics2.sourceforge.net/), its a fork of the original metrics plugin and is built for Eclipse 3.5.

Answer (score 3):

There is an [updated version](http://sourceforge.net/projects/metrics2/) of the Metrics plug-in described above that should do what you need.  It can aggregate some of the measurements (e.g. add up the LOC of classes in a package to give you the LOC of the package) and export the measurements to XML.  Some time in the near future, it should also export them to a relational database.

Comment: Metrics2 (ebt's answer) is the current name of the updated version of the Metrics plug-in.

Answer (score 3):

If you want LOC only then use  locmetric  http://www.locmetrics.com/ . and if you  want check metric and code coverage usse SONAR or Eclips CodePro Analytix  plugin.

i suggest to use  https://developers.google.com/java-dev-tools/codepro/doc/  it has  Automated tools   measure  quality  of  Java source code and code coverage

Answer (score 2):

A search for *[eclipse code+metrics](http://www.google.co.nz/search?q=eclipse+code%2Bmetrics)* turns up http://eclipse-metrics.sourceforge.net/, which looks good.

Comment: This is a snazzy one that creates warnings when the metrics start to show potential problems, but it doesn't seem to have a summary feature with overall stats.

Answer (score 2):

I also recommend the eclipse-metrics plugin.

It is capable of exporting the metrics into html, and is capable of doing this from an ant task (at least according to the documentation, I have never tried it).

The plugin works even in Eclipse 3.5 fine.

Answer (score 1):

Sonar seems worth to look at: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Installing+Sonar+in+Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Another good project is the [projectusus](https://code.google.com/p/projectusus/), which shows you not only the metrics but also whether you are respecting the standards or not and gives you a hint of what should be refactored