# EclipseMetrics plugin fails with "No typeInfo available"

Tags: java, eclipse, complexity-theory, metrics

Running Eclipse Indigo with JDK 1.7, when I use the [Metrics plugin](http://metrics.sourceforge.net/), I don't see a Metrics View, so I can't see any metrics. Also, when I try to Export -> Other -> Metrics, it fails with a "No typeInfo available" error.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this by installing the [new version of the plugin](http://metrics2.sourceforge.net/), as referenced in [akf's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1047079/6027). There weren't really any references to the new plugin from the old plugin, so it was hard to learn of the existence of the new version.

Answer (score 0):

It should work when you (temporarily) revert to an older JVM (1.6).

According to this report: http://sourceforge.net/p/eclipse-metrics/discussion/435275/thread/59501309/

Haven't tried it myself yet though.

**Edit**

I just tested this myself running Eclipse with the latest jre6 (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre6-downloads-1637595.html) and it works like a charm.